# Copying billing address to shipping address with cart.js

Tags: cartthrob

I am using the default cart.js file in my checkout which is included with CT2.5 This provides a copy billing info to shipping function which always seemed to work well, but since upgrading to CT2.5 no longer copies the billing country to shipping country, all other fields copy fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across your question now. Perhaps this answer will help others who are looking.

This link goes to an archived Cartthrob forum question/answer from April 2012 which solved the problem for me:

http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/5195/#23632

To quote:

> Are you asking about the example cart/checkout template? There looks
>   to be an error that is keeping the selects from updating in the
>   shipping fields. If you’re using the default cart, open the
>   cart/_header template and change $(“input to $(”:input in the code
>   that updates the shipping fields.

Edited to add:

As of JQuery 1.7, you should use .on() instead of .live() so you should check that out as well. Here's a brief explanation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395786/live-not-working-with-change-function

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeanne that fixes copying the billing country to the shipping country but it does not appear to dynamically change the cart totals. When I manually change the shipping country the cart totals do update. Do you notice that as well or have I introduced a new problem myself? I had a play with the default CT demo and I get the same behaviour.